# Automator Applescript - Use 1 Ask For Finder Item Selection for two different Actions

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm working on an Automator Application where the bit I'm up to has a finder selection window open within the App - Telestream Switch.

My Next steps would be:

1 Ask For Finder Item
2 Copy Path Name
3 Return to Telestream Switch App - cmd shift G and paste path name and enter - So that the file is selected.
4 Refer back to point **1** so that the finder item is selected again.
5 Run the following apple script to copy only the item name.

on run {input, parameters}

```
set fileName to first item of input

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell disk item (fileName as text) to ¬
        set {theName, theExtension} to ¬
            {name, name extension}

if theExtension is not "" then
    set theName to ¬
        text 1 thru -((count theExtension) + 2) ¬
            of theName
    set the clipboard to theName
else
    set the clipboard to theName
end if

return input
```

end run

Would this be possible?

Thanks

Comment: RE: "2 Copy Path Name" --  I do not see a **Copy Path Name** _action_  in the **Actions Library** in **Automator**. -- Is this a specific _action_ in **Automator**, maybe added by a _third-party application_?

Answer (score 0):

To refer back to the *value* of a previous *action*, you can use the **Set Value of Variable** *action* and the **Get Value of Variable** *action* as appropriate, e.g.:

- **Ask for Finder Items** *action*
- **Set Value of Variable** *action*
- Some other *action*.
- Some other *action*.
- **Get Value of Variable** *action*
- **Run AppleScript** *action*
- Some other *action*.

You should also check **[√] Ignore this action's input** in the **Options** *section* of the **Set/Get Value of Variable** *action* as appropriate so its *action* is logically disconnected from the next *action*.

In the example **Automator** *workflow* below, there would be other *actions* between the **Set Value of Variable** *action* and the **Get Value of Variable** *action* as wanted.

<sub>**Note:** If the **Run AppleScript** *action* is the last *action* in the *workflow*, then you do not need to include the `return input` line of *code*.</sub>

[image]